# Routing error when adding button with class and id from another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, haml

I'm trying to add button "contact me" to another page, that works there perfectly. That button should opens conversation message box as popup. I added in the view:

```
= link_to t('.contact_me'), new_my_conversations_path(id: @user.id), class: "btnA login #{@show_contact_me ? 'open' : ''}"
```

In the controller I added:

```
@show_contact_me = true if session.delete('openmessage') == 'yes'
```

I'm getting error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"my/conversations", :id=>nil}
```

Routes of conversation exist as:

```
namespace :my do
    resources :conversations, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show, :update, :edit]do
      get 'new/:id', on: :collection, action: :new, as: :new
    end
end
```

I tried to add to the routes:

```
resources :experiences, only: [:index, :show] do
   get '/my/conversations/new/:id' => 'conversation#new',as: :my_new_conversations
   post :remove_item, on: :collection   
end
```

Because it button should be in the experiences controller and in show method.
Still not helps.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you read rails guide about differences between namespaces, scopes and nested resources? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: yes, but I'm still beginner. And sometime it confusing me where to use them. Maybe because I didn't see many examples...

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
namespace :my do
    resources :conversations, only: [:new, :create, :index, :show, :update, :edit]do
      ##get 'new/:id', on: :collection, action: :new, as: :new
      member { get :new, as: :new }
    end
end
```

and use it ..

```
= link_to t('.contact_me'), new_my_conversations_path(@user), class: "btnA login #{@show_contact_me ? 'open' : ''}"
```

Comment: i get error: undefined method "new_my_conversations_path"